# Construct regular expression that matches numeric expressions like 5+65

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a way to construct regular expressions to match two integers with mathematical operation, like 6+36 85*52

Comment: (1) Which language? (2) What have you tried? (3) Must you use regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple mathematical operation like `Number Operator Number` you can use this regex:

```
^[0-9]+(\+|\-|\*|\/)[0-9]+$
```

For a complex expression like `Number Operator Number Operator Number...` try this:

```
^[0-9]+((\+|\-|\*|\/)[0-9]+)+$
```

Comment: Instead of `(\+|\-|\*|\/)`, you can just do `[-+*/]`; just make sure that the `-` is in first position so it is not mis-interpreted as a range. (May depend on regex dialect).